# Android Selectable TextViewer SetHighlightedText

Tags: android

I am Using `SelectableTextview` in my e-book app where i want to highlight any text from the book. The text is being highlighted by `SelectableTextViewer` class, and i am saving the selected text in database. Now i want when the user open the e-book next time the same text should be highlighted as it is. But there is no method of setting selected text.  How can i solve this problem. Please help me

**SelectableTextviewer.java**

```
public class SelectableTextViewer extends RelativeLayout {

    private ImageView imgStartSelect;
    public static int mStartSelect = -1;
    private ImageView imgEndSelect;
    public static int mEndSelect = -1;
    private int mImgWidth = 40;
    private int mImgHeight = 50;

    private TextView textView;

    private View mCurrentControlFocused;

    public static interface ISelectableTextViewerListener {


        public void updateSelection(SelectableTextViewer selectableTextViewer);

        public void endSelectingText(SelectableTextViewer selectableTextViewer,
                                     String selectedText);

        public void stopSelectingText(
                SelectableTextViewer selectableTextViewer, String selectedText);

    }

    private ISelectableTextViewerListener selectableTextViewerListener;
    public static BackgroundColorSpan spanBackgroundColored;

    public void setSelectableTextViewerListener(
            ISelectableTextViewerListener selectableTextViewerListener) {
        this.selectableTextViewerListener = selectableTextViewerListener;
    }

    public SelectableTextViewer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            this.initControls();
        }
    }

    public SelectableTextViewer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            this.initControls();
        }
    }

    public SelectableTextViewer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            this.initControls();
        }
    }

    private void initControls() {
        this.spanBackgroundColored = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW);
        this.textView = new TextView(getContext());
        this.addView(textView);
        this.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                showSelectionControls();
                int[] location = { 0, 0 };

                getLocationOnScreen(location);
                System.out.println("getLocationOnScreen:" + location[0] + "\t"
                        + location[1]);

                return false;
            }
        });

        this.createImgControllersForSelection();

    }

    protected void disallowIntercept(Boolean disallowIntercept) {
        this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept);
    }

    protected void createImgControllersForSelection() {
        this.imgStartSelect = new ImageView(getContext());
        this.imgEndSelect = new ImageView(getContext());
        this.imgStartSelect.setImageResource(R.drawable.cursor);
        this.imgEndSelect.setImageResource(R.drawable.cursor);
        this.addView(imgStartSelect, mImgWidth, mImgHeight);
        this.addView(imgEndSelect, mImgWidth, mImgHeight);
        OnClickListener onClickForChangeFocus = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentControlFocused = v;
            }
        };
        this.imgEndSelect.setOnClickListener(onClickForChangeFocus);
        this.imgStartSelect.setOnClickListener(onClickForChangeFocus);

        OnTouchListener onTouchSelectionControl = new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                disallowIntercept(true);

                mCurrentControlFocused = v;
                int eid = event.getAction();
                switch (eid) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    int[] location = { 0, 0 };

                    getLocationOnScreen(location);

                    LayoutParams mParams = (LayoutParams) v
                            .getLayoutParams();

                    int x = (int) event.getRawX();
                    int y = (int) event.getRawY();
                    // + insideScrollView.getScrollY();

                    mParams.leftMargin = x - mImgWidth / 2 - location[0];
                    if (x <= 0) {
                        mParams.leftMargin = mImgWidth;
                    } else if (x > (getMeasuredWidth() - mImgWidth)) {
                        mParams.leftMargin = getMeasuredWidth() - mImgWidth;
                    }
                    // TODO Must calculate all padding control

                    mParams.topMargin = (int) (y - (location[1] + mImgHeight * 1.5f));
                    if (mParams.topMargin <= 1) {
                        mParams.topMargin = 1;
                    }
                    v.setLayoutParams(mParams);
                    updateSelectionByMovementImgControls(mParams.leftMargin,
                            mParams.topMargin);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (selectableTextViewerListener != null) {
                        selectableTextViewerListener.endSelectingText(
                                SelectableTextViewer.this, getSelectedText());
                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    disallowIntercept(false);
                    break;
                }
                return true;

            }
        };

        this.imgEndSelect.setOnTouchListener(onTouchSelectionControl);
        this.imgStartSelect.setOnTouchListener(onTouchSelectionControl);

        this.imgEndSelect.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        this.imgStartSelect.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    public void updateSelectionByMovementImgControls(int x, int y) {
        if (mCurrentControlFocused.equals(imgStartSelect)) {
            this.mStartSelect = getOffsetByCoordinates(x + mImgWidth / 2, y);
        } else if (mCurrentControlFocused.equals(imgEndSelect)) {
            this.mEndSelect = getOffsetByCoordinates(x + mImgWidth / 2, y);
        }
        updateSelectionSpan();

    }






    protected Layout updateSelectionSpan() {
        Layout retLayout = this.textView.getLayout();
        if (this.mStartSelect > -1 && this.mEndSelect > -1) {
            if (this.mStartSelect > this.mEndSelect) {
                int temp = mEndSelect;
                this.mEndSelect = mStartSelect;
                this.mStartSelect = temp;
                showSelectionControls();
            }

            SpannedString spannable = (SpannedString) this.textView.getText();
            SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(spannable);
            ssb.removeSpan(this.spanBackgroundColored);

            ssb.setSpan(this.spanBackgroundColored, this.mStartSelect,
                    this.mEndSelect, Spannable.SPAN_USER);
            this.textView.setText(ssb);
            this.textView.requestLayout();
            if (this.selectableTextViewerListener != null) {
                this.selectableTextViewerListener.updateSelection(this);
            }
        }
        return retLayout;
    }

    protected void showSelectionControls() {
        if (this.mStartSelect > -1 && this.mEndSelect > -1) {
            Layout layout = updateSelectionSpan();

            Rect parentTextViewRect = new Rect();

            LayoutParams startLP = (LayoutParams) this.imgStartSelect
                    .getLayoutParams();
            float xStart = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(this.mStartSelect)
                    - mImgWidth / 2;
            float yStart = layout.getLineBounds(
                    layout.getLineForOffset(this.mStartSelect),
                    parentTextViewRect);
            startLP.setMargins((int) xStart, (int) yStart, -1, -1);

            this.imgStartSelect.setLayoutParams(startLP);
            this.imgStartSelect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            LayoutParams endLP = (LayoutParams) this.imgEndSelect
                    .getLayoutParams();
            float xEnd = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(this.mEndSelect)
                    - mImgWidth / 2;
            float yEnd = layout.getLineBounds(
                    layout.getLineForOffset(this.mEndSelect),
                    parentTextViewRect);
            endLP.setMargins((int) xEnd, (int) yEnd, -1, -1);
            this.imgEndSelect.setLayoutParams(endLP);
            this.imgEndSelect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (this.imgStartSelect != null) {
                if (this.imgStartSelect.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {

                    this.onTouchDownCalcSelections(event);
                    disallowIntercept(false);

                } else {
                    this.stopSelecting();

                }
            }
        } else {
            this.disallowIntercept(false);
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private void hideSelectionControls() {
        this.imgStartSelect.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        this.imgEndSelect.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    private int getOffsetByCoordinates(int x, int y) {
        int retOffset = -1;
        Layout layout = this.textView.getLayout();
        if (layout != null) {
            int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
            retOffset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);
        }
        return retOffset;
    }

    private void onTouchDownCalcSelections(MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();
        this.mStartSelect = getOffsetByCoordinates(x, y);
        if (this.mStartSelect > -1) {
            // Calculate text end
            String tempStr = this.textView.getText().toString();
            tempStr = tempStr.substring(this.mStartSelect);
            Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("\\s");
            Matcher mt = pt.matcher(tempStr);
            if (mt.find()) {
                String match = mt.group(0);
                tempStr = tempStr.substring(0, tempStr.indexOf(match));
            }
            this.mEndSelect = this.mStartSelect + tempStr.length();
        }
    }

    public void setText(SpannableStringBuilder builder) {
        this.textView.setText(builder);

    }

    public ImageView getImgEndSelect() {
        return imgEndSelect;
    }

    public ImageView getImgStartSelect() {
        return imgStartSelect;
    }

    /**
     * For this all doing
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String getSelectedText() {
        String retSelectedString = null;
        if (this.mStartSelect > -1 && this.mEndSelect > -1) {
            retSelectedString = this.textView.getText()
                    .subSequence(this.mStartSelect, this.mEndSelect).toString();
        }
        return retSelectedString;
    }

    /**
     * Hides cursors and clears
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public void stopSelecting() {
        this.hideSelectionControls();
        SpannedString spannable = (SpannedString) this.textView.getText();
        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(spannable);
        ssb.removeSpan(this.spanBackgroundColored);
        this.setText(ssb);
        if (selectableTextViewerListener != null) {
            selectableTextViewerListener.stopSelectingText(
                    SelectableTextViewer.this, getSelectedText());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to this method as re-use, customize this method as per your use. this is just a concept.

// text comes from textview.gettext or database text and invalidate the view.

```
protected Layout updateSelectionSpan(Strint text) {
    Layout retLayout = this.textView.getLayout();
    if (this.mStartSelect > -1 && this.mEndSelect > -1) {
        if (this.mStartSelect > this.mEndSelect) {
            int temp = mEndSelect;
            this.mEndSelect = mStartSelect;
            this.mStartSelect = temp;
            showSelectionControls();
        }

        SpannedString spannable = (SpannedString) text;
        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(spannable);
        ssb.removeSpan(this.spanBackgroundColored);

        ssb.setSpan(this.spanBackgroundColored, this.mStartSelect,
                this.mEndSelect, Spannable.SPAN_USER);
        this.textView.setText(ssb);
        this.textView.requestLayout();
        if (this.selectableTextViewerListener != null) {
            this.selectableTextViewerListener.updateSelection(this);
        }
    }
    return retLayout;
}
```